How to set Chromium flag to use custom user profile
I am working on an application that requires Microsoft SSO for user authentication but have encountered a challenge while using a monitoring tool named Dynatrace. Specifically, when trying to replay user sessions in incognito mode, the application remains inaccessible without the Microsoft SSO plugin/extension.
Is there a method to set the user profile using a Chromium flag while loading the Chrome browser? This would significantly help in overcoming the limitation posed by the necessity of the SSO extension during monitoring.
I am currently facing an issue with loading a user profile to use the Microsoft SSO extension while checking for Chromium flags. I attempted to create a profile for a service account and that worked well for an application. However, my goal is to avoid hardcoding the user profile.
I would like to have it used only during the URL synthetic replay time.

You seem just need to enable "Allow in Incognito" in the extension settings.
